# Save to buffer instead of file when recording aac with Audio Queue Services

Tags: objective-c, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, audioqueueservices

My goal is to record audio in AAC format and send it over a network connection as a stream.

I'm using Audio Queue Services and have based my code on the SpeakHere example. I know that for writing to a file it uses the AudioFileWritePackets() function.

Here's the callback function:

```
void MyInputBufferHandler(void* inUserData,
                          AudioQueueRef inAQ,
                          AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
                          const AudioTimeStamp * inStartTime,
                          UInt32 inNumPackets,
                          const AudioStreamPacketDescription* inPacketDesc) {

    Recorder *aqr = (Recorder *)inUserData;

    if (inNumPackets > 0) {
        // write packets to file
        AudioFileWritePackets(aqr->mRecordFile, FALSE,
                              inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                              inPacketDesc, aqr->mRecordPacket, 
                              &inNumPackets, inBuffer->mAudioData);

        aqr->mRecordPacket += inNumPackets;
    }

    // if we're not stopping, re-enqueue the buffe so that it gets filled again
    if ([aqr IsRunning])
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
```

At first I thought *AudioFileWritePackets* works by directly writing the content of `inBuffer->mAudioData`. However when I manually write just the contents of mAudioData to a file the decoding doesn't seem to work.

On examining and comparing the raw data of what *AudioFileWritePackets* writes to a file and of me just writing mAudioData to a file, they seem to have attached a header to it.

As I can't find out how *AudioFileWritePackets()* works inside, my question is, how can I write the recorded audio to a buffer (or stream, if you prefer to call it this way) instead of a file, so that I can later send it over a network connection?

Again, in short here's what I need: record audio in aac format and stream the audio over network connection.

Thanks! I've been searching my head blue...

P.S: please if you point me to existing projects, make sure they are what I need. I really feel like I've been looking for all possible projects out there >.<

Comment: I wrote a very similar program, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537302/upload-audio-http-streaming/10692772#10692772

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

Check the ["HandleInputBuffer" method in "SpeechToTextModule.m".](https://github.com/iz3/SpeechToText/blob/master/iPhone-Speech-To-Text-Library/SpeechToTextModule.m)